# What's wrong with this SQL procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm getting error in this stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spc_InsertSubjectToContentRelation]
(
    @pCourseGUID NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @pAssessmentIds NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @pSubjectId NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @pVideoIds NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SubjectToAssessmentAndVideoRelation WHERE SubjectId = @pSubjectId AND CourseGuid = @pCourseGuid)
   UPDATE SubjectToAssessmentAndVideoRelation SET (AssociatedAssessments = @pAssessmentIds, AssociatedVideos = @pVideoIds) WHERE SubjectId = @pSubjectId AND CourseGuid = @pCourseGuid
ELSE
    INSERT INTO SubjectToAssessmentAndVideoRelation VALUES (@pCourseGUID, @pAssessmentIds, @pSubjectId, @pVideoIds)
END
```

The error is:

> Procedure spc_InsertSubjectToContentRelation, Line 14
> Incorrect syntax near '('.

What is wrong in this query?

## EDIT:

I forgot to add `EXISTS` while posting the code. My actual code was with exist. I'm getting the error with exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `IF` statement is not doing anything, it only contains an expression:

```
IF  (SELECT * FROM SubjectToAssessmentAndVideoRelation WHERE SubjectId = @pSubjectId AND CourseGuid = @pCourseGuid)
```

It needs to be something like:

```
IF  (SELECT * FROM SubjectToAssessmentAndVideoRelation WHERE SubjectId = @pSubjectId AND CourseGuid = @pCourseGuid) = 0
```

--Then do your logic

You may instead be after something like this by using `IF EXISTS`:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SubjectToAssessmentAndVideoRelation WHERE SubjectId = @pSubjectId AND CourseGuid = @pCourseGuid)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I changed to `IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SubjectToAssessmentAndVideoRelation WHERE SubjectId = @pSubjectId AND CourseGuid = @pCourseGuid)`, Still it didn't work. I'm getting the same error

Comment: Apologies, I didn't notice the brackets around your UPDATE statement. You need to remove the ( and ) where you have input your SET clause.

Answer (score 2):

```
IF  (SELECT * FROM SubjectToAssessmentAndVideoRelation WHERE SubjectId = @pSubjectId AND CourseGuid = @pCourseGuid)
```

This isn't a valid test. Did you mean `IF EXISTS(...`?

Comment: I changed to `IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SubjectToAssessmentAndVideoRelation WHERE SubjectId = @pSubjectId AND CourseGuid = @pCourseGuid)`, Still it didn't work. I'm getting the same error